# .htaccess file prevents images from loading

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got an `.htaccess` file which I use to rewrite my urls.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^configurator/(.+)$ configurator.php?pc=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ product.php?product=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Inside my configurator my images are not loading. If I disable the .htaccess file and I go the the path of my images they load.
How can i make my .htaccess file not block image loading?

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my solution has helped you?

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts, please try following. make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also make sure that your htaccess rules file is present in same folder where folders (configurator, product) are present.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^configurator/(.+)/?$ configurator.php?pc=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)/?$ product.php?product=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```